# Matching of Vertices with Maximal Degree in Bipartite Graph

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let G be a bipartite graph and let A be the set of vertices of maximal
degree. Show that there is a matching in G that covers A where A is not necessarily in one partite.

I am trying to apply a similar proof as that of Konig's Theorem but I am having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add more edges (and maybe more vertices) until the bipartite graph is $\Delta(G)$-regular. What can you say about regular bipartite graphs?

Comment: I don't think we can use this

Comment: Why not? Sounds like fair game to prove a generalization using a basic lemma.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Regular bipartite graphs have perfect matchings.

Comment: and how do we use that?

Comment: Aw man, you want me to spoil the entire solution? Well, consider what happens when you remove all the extra edges.

Comment: What happens? ${}{}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107012/discussion-between-magma-and-jorge-fernandez-hidalgo).

Comment: thank you so much! I was really over thinking it.